# How can I include dependencies for compilation in a Bazel rule

Tags: c++, compilation, bazel

I'm trying to create a Bazel rule that takes a .yaml file, uses the information in it to generate source code, compiles and archives it as a static lib like a `cc_library` would and can be depended on by cc_rules.

I could create a rule that generates my source code and wrap it in a cc_library macro, but I would like to avoid having different names for the target creating the source code, and the target created by the macro.

So I followed [this example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/examples/my_c_compile/my_c_compile.bzl) to get started writing that rule but I'm getting stuck at how to include my dependencies. Assuming I have a `deps` attribute in my rule, what's the best way to include those dependencies in my compiler command?

```py
cpp_compile_variables = cc_common.create_compile_variables(
        feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
        cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
        user_compile_flags = ctx.fragments.cpp.copts,
        source_file = type_publisher.path,
        output_file = type_publisher_object_file.path,
        include_directories = [dep.attrs.hdrs for dep in ctx.files.deps]
    )
```

In this snippet, the `include_directories` parameter is incorrect. How can I include all the header files related to the targets provided in the `deps` attribute specified in the build file?

Answer (score 1):

You are going down the path of reimplementing the builtin C++ rules. There's [a lot](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/main/starlark/builtins_bzl/common/cc) to them! So, I would not recommend this for your fairly simple task.

What's the trouble with code generation being a separate target? There is [a proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p6z-shWf9sdqo_ep7dcjZCGvqN5r2jsPkJCqHHgfRp4/edit#heading=h.kzp6mqja2p3t) that [if implemented](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/19507) would allow `cc_library` to be reused within another rule. Until that feature exists, though, it's probably going to be simplest to live with code generation as another target.

Comment: One of the reasons is redability. My code generation rule receives the name it is passed to generate files with a specific name. I would like users to be able to use the names they declare, rather than an implicit name created by the macro, but they also need to be able to specify the name passed to the generation rule.

I'd also like to know, regardless of the possible solution to my problem, how includes from dependencies can be added to create_compile_variable

Comment: The `include_directories` parameter to create the compile variables will just be strings that are added to compilation command line. The actual headers of your dependencies will be found on the compilation contexts (i.e., `dep[CcInfo].compilation_context`) on all of your dependencies.